# Grant permission to user

Tags: sql-server-2008

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "ahsan" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.

Please tell me solution of this error.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to impersonate a database principal called "ahsan".  One of the following problems is occurring:

- The principal doesn't exist (no user of that name)

  - **Solution:** *Create the user*
- It's of a type that can't be impersonated (AD groups, for example, can't be impersonated)

  - **Solution:** *There isn't one*
- You don't have permissions to impersonate the principal.

  - **Solution:** *Try to impersonate the principal with a user/login that has permissions or get yourself granted the correct permissions.*

There is absolutely no way to tell you which of these it is without additional information.